# Single plot with variables from 2 dfs with different x date scale

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, plot, linechart

I have a df which looks like this (I copied only a part of the dataset which has a date  variable **%Y%m%d** from 1996-10-23 until 2022-12-14, with some missing days).

```
PSA <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15657, 15665, 15671, 15672, 
15678, 15679, 15685, 15686, 15693, 15714, 15721, 15728, 15735, 
15742, 15749, 15763, 15770, 15777, 15779, 15780, 15784, 15785, 
15789, 15790, 15791, 15797, 15798, 15804, 15805, 15810, 15811, 
15812, 15819, 15819, 15824, 15825, 15831, 15832, 15832, 15833, 
15839, 15839, 15840, 15840, 15841, 15846, 15846, 15847, 15848, 
15853, 15854, 15855, 15859, 15860, 15860, 15861, 15861, 15862, 
15867, 15867, 15868, 15868, 15869, 15874, 15874, 15875, 15875, 
15876, 15880, 15881, 15881, 15882, 15882, 15883, 15888, 15888, 
15889, 15889, 15890, 15894, 15895, 15895, 15896, 15896, 15897, 
15901, 15902, 15902, 15903, 15903, 15904, 15905, 15909, 15909, 
15910, 15911, 15912, 15915, 15916, 15916, 15917), class = "Date"), 
    country = c("Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "United Kingdom", 
    "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
    "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
    "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
    "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "United Kingdom", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy"), propIT_econ = c(20, 
    0, 12.5, 0, 12.5, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 5.26315789473684, 0, 0, 28.5714285714286, 0, 5.55555555555556, 
    23.5294117647059, 3.50877192982456, 21.0526315789474, 2.72727272727273, 
    0, 2.85714285714286, 0, 0.840336134453782, 0, 9.09090909090909, 
    14.5454545454545, 30.2325581395349, 13.5593220338983, 13.5593220338983, 
    2.85714285714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.54545454545455, 5.61797752808989, 
    5.61797752808989, 0, 0, 0, 2.1505376344086, 4.8780487804878, 
    30, 3.2520325203252, 3.2520325203252, 3.77358490566038, 0, 
    3.06122448979592, 0, 2.01342281879195, 0, 0, 6.66666666666667, 
    4.65116279069767, 0, 0.975609756097561, 0, 1.53846153846154, 
    0, 11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 5.14705882352941, 
    0, 1.61290322580645, 4.1958041958042, 4.1958041958042, 0.271739130434783, 
    0, 1.81818181818182, 7.2463768115942, 7.14285714285714, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 13.5135135135135, 10.8108108108108, 10.8108108108108, 
    2.21606648199446, 0, 3.92156862745098, 8.57142857142857, 
    2.84090909090909, 2.84090909090909, 3.68421052631579, 9.61538461538462, 
    0, 1.44927536231884, 0.235849056603774, 0, 1.44230769230769
    ), propUK_econ = c(0, 0, 0, 1.51515151515152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1.38888888888889, 1.53846153846154, 1.53846153846154, 
    2.85714285714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.22535211267606, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.840336134453782, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Then I transformed it into long format:

```
PSAlong <- PSA %>% gather(variable, value, -date, -country)
```

I have also another df, which starts from 2004 until 2022 and has a date variable which is instead **%Y%qrt**.

```
MIP_nat <- structure(list(date = c("2004.3", "2005.1", "2005.3", "2006.1", 
"2006.3", "2007.1"), season = c("autumn", "spring", "autumn", 
"spring", "autumn", "spring"), country = c("Italy", "Italy", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy"), Crime = c(23, 23, 25, 22, 
25, 28), Public_transport = c(4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0), Economic_situation = c(31, 
37, 31, 33, 33, 28), Rising_prices_inflation = c(29, 32, 31, 
28, 25, 26), Taxation = c(16, 14, 12, 15, 15, 18), Un_employment = c(31, 
36, 31, 36, 30, 28), Terrorism = c(17, 7, 11, 7, 15, 9), Country_external_influence = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Government_debt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Defence_Foreign_affairs = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1), Cyprus_issue = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Housing = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 2), Immigration = c(17, 15, 15, 14, 20, 15), Health_social_security = c(5, 
6, 6, 5, 6, 5), Education = c(3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2), Pensions = c(9, 
7, 10, 6, 9, 11), Environment_climate_energy = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 
6, 9), International_situation = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Other = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1), None = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DN = c(0, 0, 1, 4, 
0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I tried to transform the date variable as a date with this code, but returns NAs

```
MIP_nat$date <- as.yearqtr(MIP_nat$date)
```

I would like to have a plot combining the values of the variable **"propIT_econ" and "propUK_econ" from the first df (PSAlong)** and the variable **"Economic_situation" from the second df (MIP_nat)**, either with the same scale of with two x_axis with different scales.

I am struggling because of the two different format of the date variables, which allows me to have only the variable of a df, not both. For example, this works fine:
I run only the first plot with this code instead and it works

```
PSAlong %>% filter(variable == "propIT_econ" | variable == "propUK_econ") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(date), y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_step(linewidth = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",
    date_labels = "%Y")
```

I tried this it doesn't produce what I have in mind:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = PSAlong %>% filter(variable == "propIT_econ" | variable == "propUK_econ),
            aes(x = as.numeric(date), y = value, color = country)) +
  geom_line(data = MIP_nat,
            aes(x = as.numeric(date), y = "Economic_situation", linetype = country)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1996,2023),
                     breaks = seq(1997,2023, by = 1))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra column in `MIP_nat` which you construct from its `date` column replacing *year.1* with *year/02/15*, *year.2* with *year/05/15*, *year.3* with *year/08/15* and *year/11/15* (or whichever date of the year, you want the quarter referring to).

Use `str_extract` and `str_replace` (maybe `str_extract_all` and `str_replace_all`) from the `stringr` package to achieve this. It involves fiddling with *regular expressions* (ugh!) though (learning by doing at [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)).